# how to use .less files in adobe CQ5?

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem, wcm

i'm new in Adobe CQ5, and developing CMS Application using this, i create ClienLibraryFolder in following directory:

```
/etc/designs/MySiteName/ClientLibFolder/MyLess.less
```

but when i'm using this on .jsp file it is not design anything what i defined in .less file, while using .css files i'm getting all things. can anyone suggest me what i'm missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have added the MyLess.less to the css.txt in /etc/designs/MySiteName/ClientLibFolder.

The next step would be to ensure the OSGI bundle is running which compiles the less file.  For information on where the bundle is located you can refer to this blog post http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2012/08/less_css_in_adobecq.html